# Multpile sets of rules in altium (Rules by selected area)

Tags: altium

I'm new with altium and i'm trying to make a 12V power supply.
I don't want it to overheat more than 20 degrees, so I need to put a trace of at least 4,75 mm... My problem is that when I change the Rules in altium, it changes it for all the document. Is there a way to apply a rule on only a certain Area of the pcb? I tried using rooms, but it seems I cannot put a rule on it... Other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 'Net class' called something like 'Power' and make a rule that applies to nets in that class only, then add the heavy current nets to that class.

You can also do things like add rules to change clearances and polygon connect styles to such a class which can be useful.

Altium is very much rule driven design, it pays off bigtime to learn the intricacies of the netclass and component class systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a powerpad user, however PCB drawing software are almost identical.

You should use copper pour instead of trace for heat sink. Do ensure the copper is same net as the trace you want to connect.

If you do not like thermal pad generated by the system when using pour, you may try just copper. It's just smack a piece of rectangular box on your PCB.

Comment: Also an alternative from the first answer, thank you. So I should pour a copper polygon and then When I trace, makes the separations by itself?

Comment: Is the trace same net with the copper? If yes, the copper would flood with the trace. If not, the copper pour will avoid the trace.

Comment: Okay, but what I'm asking is how to make Altium make that trace clearance of 2mm by itself using all the rest of the copper pour. Is there a way other than manually?

Comment: http://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/PCB_Dlg-ClearanceRule_Frame((Clearance))_AD The enter key on android is the reply key, lol. I just google, you can set clearence in the copper settings.